# How does CCI Indexing works?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

While creating a CCI Index in SQL Server, we don't have to specify the column name So on which column does the CCI Creates Index? Does CCI Index also sorts the table based on a column like clustered Indexing?

Comment: Columnstore indexes do not imply sorting/ordering (unlike traditional b-tree indexes). No column list is specified with a CCI because every column in the table is a separate columnstore structures. See [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview) for more info.

Comment: You should read the plentiful documentation on columnstore indexes and then ask about anything unclear - not ask questions that would be answered by basic documentation in lieu of having to read it.